# How do you display the command arguments in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a project in C++ (using Visual Studio 2013), and I know that if i want to pass command arguments I have to go to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging and then type the command in "Command Arguments".

But I'd like to see those command arguments in the actual program (after I click "Start without debugging"), since I can only see the output, without the command.

Comment: Print them from your application?

Comment: Your entry point should look like this - `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` The arguments are in `argv`.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, My code works and I already typed the arguments. But I want to see them once I run the program (in cmd.exe)

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, I want to print the arguments, too. Right now I can't see them once I run my application.

Comment: And what's stopping you from printing them?

Comment: @Jack. Where/how do you want to see them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "arg[" << i << "]: " << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

arg[0]: C:\VS2015\PrintCmdArgs\Debug\PrintCmdArgs.exe

arg[1]: here

arg[2]: are

arg[3]: some

arg[4]: arguments

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Might want to remove "Press any key to continue . . ." because your program doesn't look like it says that.

Comment: you welcome Jack. @user4581301 , this is what you see when you start without debugging, and this is what the question is all about, so i'm not removing "Press any key to continue . . ."

Answer (score 4):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << "argument " << i << " = " << argv[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can "see" the command arguments once the program has started running.

1. Simply print them from `main`.
2. If you need to display them in a form or print them while the application is running then you'll need to copy the arguments to some global/static variable and then access that when you need to.